# To what extent was Catch-22 inspired by "The Trial"?

Tags: inspiration, catch-22, joseph-heller, franz-kafka, the-trial

Bureaucratic logic is one of the primary themes in *Catch-22*. To what extent is this inspired by *The Trial* by Franz Kafka? Both have the sense of being caught in the cogs of a remote, irrational, and soulless bureaucracy, but are there more concrete examples of the influence of *The Trial* on *Catch-22*?